# Nexus 7 HTML5 video tries to hide system UI and fails over and over

Tags: android, html, video, webview

I am working on an android application that uses webview to pull in websites.  I have sucessfuly gotten HTML 5 videos to play both in the page and in full screen.  This works flawlessly on my nexus phone.  However when testing on the nexus 7, in full screen landscape mode, it appears the view is trying to hide the System UI navigation when it hides the video controls.  It immediately snaps back causing the controls to come back, and the process repeats.

Here is what is in the logs:

```
03-02 00:45:45.641   488   501 I ActivityManager: Config changes=1480 {1.0 310mcc?mnc en_US ldltr sw600dp w961dp h528dp 213dpi lrg land finger -keyb/v/h -nav/h s.585}
03-02 00:45:48.841   488  1143 W InputMethodManagerService: Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@425e74a8 attribute=null, token = android.os.BinderProxy@416975b8
03-02 00:45:52.231   488  3300 W InputMethodManagerService: Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@41ea5b20 attribute=null, token = android.os.BinderProxy@416975b8
03-02 00:45:57.811   488  1164 W InputMethodManagerService: Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@41bec5b8 attribute=null, token = android.os.BinderProxy@416975b8
```

Comment: But what is the problem/question exactly? Those logs are not related to your code.

Comment: That is what is being logged when the issues is happening, and the time it takes for the controls to auto hide is about 4 seconds. The problem is that the video controls won't stay hid because the system UI navigation is not allowing itself to be hid.

Comment: And these logs ONLY appear on a nexus 7 in fullscreen landscape mode? They don't appear on you mobile phone in landscape mode?

Comment: Gnexus does log the same line, but doesn't have the repeated Behavior.  When playing a video in chrome, the controls go away, and the system nav remains.  This is how I want it to work.

Comment: The difference between the two i think is that the tablet nav is stricter than on a phone, or so I have read.

Comment: I was able to fix the problem by             getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE);  The UI goes away and stays away, but it left with a gray bar.  This is good enough for now, but I would prefer to either leave the bar, or at least change that to black.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have seen this behaviour, and worse. HTML5 in Chrome for Nexus 7 is not ready for prime time.

Solution: Complain to Google and wait.